# Dynamic ZXing scanner dimensions / zxing_scanner_layout

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using the ZXing library to scan barcodes. Is there any way to set the `app:zxing_scanner_layout` value below in runtime from the activity, to specify different layouts? I would like to have multiple layouts / scanner dimensions depending on what barcode types that are selected.

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:zxing_scanner_layout="@layout/custom_scanner">
</com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView>
```

Option 2 would be to alter the width and height directly:

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
    app:zxing_framing_rect_width="350dp"
    app:zxing_framing_rect_height="200dp"/>
```

So I guess the question comes down to, can `app:` values be edited in runtime? Perhaps there's another way to change the dimensions programatically? I haven't seen them exposed anywhere.

Comment: I don't think there's any way, unless you want to fork the project. I've looked it myself and I've come to this conclusion unfortunately.